# What is the correct approach to passing a std::ranges::view type object to a class?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

this question concerns having a `std::ranges::view` type object as a member variable of a class. I'm trying to better understand them so I may write some poor code along the way here!

Suppose we have a function `foo()` which interfaces with the some data source and returns a `std::tuple` of range views:

```
auto foo(int i)
{
  auto v1 = views::iota(i) | views::transform([](int i){ return i++; });
  auto v2 = views::iota(i) | views::filter([](int i){ return i % 2; });
  auto v3 = views::iota(i) | views::transform([](int i){ return i += 3; });
  return std::make_tuple(v1,v2,v3);
}
```

and we then need to do some processing which involves the three return views of `foo()`, with there being some interdependence between them. Therefore, I'd like to store them as members of a class, but i'd like to avoid copying the entirety of the underlying data, so I do something like:

```
template<ranges::view Vx, ranges::view Vy, ranges::view Vz>
struct Processor
{
public:
    Processor(Vx&& x, Vy&& y, Vz&& z) : m_x{x}, m_y{y}, m_z{z} {}

    auto bar() { /* work using m_x, m_y and m_z */ }

private:
    Vx m_x;
    Vy m_y;
    Vz m_z;
};
```

in which case i'd have to initialise an instance of `Processor` using `std::move`, like so:

```
auto [x,y,x] = foo(10);
Processor p(std::move(x), std::move(y), std::move(z));
```

Or alternatively, I take `x`,`y` and `z` by value in the constructor of `Processor` i.e. `Processor(Vx x, Vy y, Vz z) : m_x{x}, m_y{y}, m_z{z} {}` and can then construct an instance as:

```
auto [x,y,x] = foo(10);
Processor p(x, y, z);
```

So, i'd just like to clarify (a) whether this is a good idea and (b) which approach should i be taking of the two? I suspect that pass-by-value is correct (value-semantics, right?) since we are not copying the underlying data, only the view of each one.

Finally, is there any way to constrain the template parameters of `Processor` further, for example writing something like `ranges::view<int>` if I know the underlying type of each range when I pass it to the constructor?

Thank you! godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/Gx419949n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views are generally passed by value since usually it doesn't own the data, it just keeps a pointer to the data (of course there are a few exceptions such as `single_view`), so `Processor(Vx x, Vy y, Vz z)` should be preferred.

However, it's important to note that views are *only* guaranteed to be movable. For example, the standard `owning_view` is a move-only view, so you should ensure that the value is moved to the member in the member initializer list

```
template<ranges::view Vx, ranges::view Vy, ranges::view Vz>
struct Processor
{
public:
  Processor(Vx x, Vy y, Vz z) 
    : m_x{std::move(x)}, m_y{std::move(y)}, m_z{std::move(z)} {}
private:
  Vx m_x;
  Vy m_y;
  Vz m_z;
}
```

> Finally, is there any way to constrain the template parameters of
> `Processor` further, for example writing something like
> ranges::view if I know the underlying type of each range when I
> pass it to the constructor?

You can use the requires clause for additional constraint checking

```
template<ranges::view Vx, ranges::view Vy, ranges::view Vz>
  requires std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<Vx>, int> && 
           std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<Vy>, int> && 
           std::same_as<std::ranges::range_value_t<Vz>, int>
struct Processor {
  // ...
};
```

Comment: I see, thank you. You suggest that I `std::move()` the arguments in the constructor to the class member variables, but if the view is non-copyable then when I call the constructor (passing the arguments by value) wouldn't that invoke a copy? In which case, i'd get a compilation in any case? Surely, in this case, the arguments to the ctor should be r-value references?

Comment: @JonahF In that case, you need to explicitly move the non-copyable view to the `Processor` member like `Processor p(std::move(x), std::move(y), std::move(z))`.

Comment: Ok I see, and that at no point would create any copies?